# Someone sent me an Excel Online link that is too big to view online -- how do I download?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, office-web-apps

Someone sent me an Excel document hosted on their organization's SharePoint server with a URL that looks like this:

https://REDACTED.sharepoint.com/personal/REDACTED_org/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?docid=REDACTED&authkey=REDACTED&action=view

When I click on this link, it just says "Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the file size limit.", and doesn't give me an option to download. Is there a workaround where I can get the server to let me download the document?

This is someone else's SharePoint instance, so I don't have login access or anything like that. The person sending the document refuses to send it any other way so I really need to get the document out of this link somehow.

I don't know what version of SharePoint they're running, but I notice their HTTP responses included this header, if it helps: `MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6830`

Comment: You should ask for the download link instead of the view link. If it gives, "access denied", then that is also something they will need to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 10MB if this excel file is stored in the SharePoint Library. More information [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/File-size-limits-for-workbooks-in-SharePoint-Online-9e5bc6f8-018f-415a-b890-5452687b325e)

You should receive this error which will allow you to Open file in Excel.

[image]

If you don't see this dialog box it might be that the user has only granted 'View' permission.  Looking at the url **'action=view'** it seems that you have only View only access which means 'View only' not to be downloaded so as far as I know it is not possible. You will receive a dialog box like:

[image]

Comment: Well, they might have more access, but have only been given the view link. Is there something the OP could change the `=view` part to, which would attempt to download the file instead?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by having my customer zip the file and share the archive, using the same sharing method. That gave me a Download option to save to my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the document in microsoft edge. It gives you an option to use desktop app to access the document; that will help you save the file on your system. I have tried it and it works!